# How to create dynamic length Json array in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am using Groovy in Soap UI.  I have requirement to create dynamic JSON
array.  Let's say I am getting an count as 12, then I need to create
a JSON Array as `{["ID": 1234,"Desc":"Apple"]}` and I have to repeat
`ID` and `Desc` with different values to create 12 array object in
single JSON.

```
def IDValue = ... // One Array where all IDs are stored
def Description = ... // Second Array where all desc are stored
JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder()
for(int i=0; i<Array.length; i++) {
    def currIDValue = IDValue[i] 
    def currDescription =Description[i]
    builder{Details([i].collect{[id : currIDValue,"Desc": currDescription]})}
}

Log.info builder.toPrettyString()
```

While print only last value is coming of both the array in JSON I have
wanted all the values should come in JSON as JSON objects in Detail
array

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Added Code. Please verify and help

Answer (score 0):

​Does this helps you :

```
import groovy.json.*
def IDValue = [1,2,3,4]
def Description = ["decs1","decs2","decs3","decs4"]
def array=[]

for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   array+=["Id": IDValue[i], "Desc":Description[i]]
}

JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder(array)
println builder.toPrettyString()​
```

Comment: ID and Desc value will come from other arrays and it should be in Json.
Code is added in the main question

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the two arrays and then collect over the resulting
pairs.  E.g.

```
def ids = [1,2,3,]
def descs = ["a", "b", "c",]

[ids, descs].transpose().collect{ id, desc -> [id: id, desc: desc] }
// → [[id:1, desc:a], [id:2, desc:b], [id:3, desc:c]]
```